# Proving $R +r\le h_{max} $

Tags: geometry

If $R$ is the circumradius , $r$ the inradius and $ h_{max}$ is the largest altitude of acute angled triangle $ABC$, then prove that $$R +r\le h_{max}. $$
I tried this using Euler's inequality but I did not succeed.

Comment: I forgot to mention that triangle ABC is acute. Does it affect the answer

Comment: it is relevant in order to make my $(2)$ work. Have also a look at http://www.gogeometry.com/geometry/carnot_theorem_acute_triangle_incircle_circumcircle_radius_plane_geometry.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assuming $a\leq b\leq c$ we have that the greatest altitude is $h_a$ and:

$$ R = \frac{abc}{4\Delta},\quad r=\frac{2\Delta}{a+b+c},\quad h_a=\frac{2\Delta}{a} $$
so, by Heron's formula, we have to prove that:

$$ 2abc + (-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) \leq \frac{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}{a} $$
or:
$$2a^2 bc\leq(b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)\tag{1}$$
where $2a^2\leq(b+c)(b+c-a)$ is trivial (since $c\geq b\geq a$) and
$$ bc \leq (a-b+c)(a+b-c) = a^2-(b-c)^2 $$
is equivalent to:
$$ b^2+c^2-bc \leq a^2 \tag{2}$$
that follows from the cosine theorem, since $\widehat{A}\leq\frac{\pi}{3}$ (otherwise, $a$ cannot be the shortest side).